# What is the correct formula for calculating Percentile

Tags: self-study

There are two formulas that are typically given for calculating Rank associated with a percentile. They are as follows

$$1) Rank = \frac{Percentile}{100} \cdot (N+1)$$
$$2) Rank = \frac{Percentile}{100} \cdot N \quad ~ ~ \quad$$

Here Rank is the rank of the values/data points. 
N is the number of items or values or data points for which percentile is sought to be used
Percentile is the actual percentile value that we are looking to hit, for example in case of Median we will take this as 50.

My question is what is the correct formula that should be used.

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE. If I understood your question correctly, there are [several formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile#Estimating_quantiles_from_a_sample) for the computation of quantiles or percentiles, and no consensus on which is the correct one, since each have their own assumptions. By the way, see some tips on [how to ask](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and on [formatting help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and write down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). I've submitted an edit for the equations.

Comment: I prefer to use the linear interpolation formula [R-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile#Estimating_quantiles_from_a_sample): $h = (N-1)p+1$, where $p \in [0; 1]$. If you want an integer rank you may round $h$, but if you want the quantile, you'll need to compute the second part of the formula.

Comment: Use the formula that inverts the formula used to compute the percentile in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @Ertxiem. You understood my question correctly. Apart from this there is the weighted mean method too. The edit for the formula in the question was helpful. I will consider it.

Comment: @whuber can you please elaborate a bit on your statement.

Comment: Anirudh: I've ported my comments to an answer and tried to explain @whuber's comment. I hope I went in the intended direction.

Answer (score 2):

There are [several formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile#Estimating_quantiles_from_a_sample) for the computation of quantiles or percentiles, and no consensus on which is the correct one, since each have their own assumptions.

I prefer to use the linear interpolation formula [R-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile#Estimating_quantiles_from_a_sample): 
$$
h = (N−1) p + 1 \ , 
$$
where $p \in [0;1]$. If you want an integer rank you may round $h$, but if you want the quantile, you'll need to compute the second part of the formula:
$$
Q = x_k + (h − k) (x_{k + 1} − x_k) \ ,
$$
where $k = \lfloor h \rfloor$ is the value of $h$ rounded down.
This formula makes a linear interpolation between the value of the $k$-th value in ascending order and the $(k+1)$-th value in ascending order. Being closer to the latter if $h-k \in [0; 1)$ is closer to $1$.

---

If you already have the quantile, you can compute its approximate rank, using these formulas in the reverse order. For instance, if the quantile is slightly larger than the third value out of $N=10$, then, using the first formula in my post, we get that $h$ will be slightly larger than $3$ ($h$ will be between $3$ and $4$, and we can compute $p$:
$$
p = \frac{h - 1}{N - 1}
$$
So, in this example, $p$ will be slightly above the percentile $22\%$, being in $\left[\frac{2}{9}; \frac{3}{9}\right]$.